# Get a Resource from a ResourceDictionary with various Resource Dictionary with a key

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

I need to have in a single file resources into a ResourceDictionary element with various resourceDictionary with key

The next code is a sample of this:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/ presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
 xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

  <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Configuration">
        <sys:String x:Key="_Conf_Delete_instr">Delete instrument</sys:String>
  </ResourceDictionary>
<ResourceDictionary x:Key="Report">
        <sys:String x:Key="mykey2">myvalue2</sys:String>
  </ResourceDictionary>
</ResourceDictionary>


I wonder if when defining the content of an element can access the ResourceDictionary indicating the key:

   <Button x:Name="btnDeleteInst" Content="{DynamicResource _Conf_Delete_instr}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,23,245,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="50" MinWidth="100" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Click="btnDeleteInstr_Click"/>
```

The previous code throws an error on _Conf_Delete_instr because `Key` isnt found.

How I can access the resource _Conf_Delete_instr included in ResourceDictionary with key "Configuration"? With a converter?

Thanks.

Comment: Try to nest your other ResourceDictionarys in `MergedDictionaries`

Comment: Hi. Thanks for you reply. I need a single resource file. If I nest my other resourceDictionarys elements (with key) in mergeddictionaris i have this error: "the key attribute can only be used in a tag embedded in a property of type Idictionary". Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have an example:

```
  <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary x:Name="Configuration">
                    <sys:String x:Key="_Conf_Delete_instr">Delete instrument</sys:String>
                </ResourceDictionary>
                <ResourceDictionary x:Name="Report">
                    <sys:String x:Key="mykey2">myvalue2</sys:String>
                </ResourceDictionary>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

**Test**

```
<Button x:Name="btnDeleteInst" Content="{DynamicResource mykey2}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,23,245,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="50" MinWidth="100" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" />

<Button x:Name="btnDeleteInst1" Content="{DynamicResource _Conf_Delete_instr}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,23,245,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="50" MinWidth="100" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" />
```

**Result**

[image: Result]